# Excel web access data ( graphs) is showing gray color on SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using "Excel Web Access" Web Parts to show the excel graphs in my MOSS2007 setup. I have multiple team sites under one site-collection. Excel web access is fine for all the team sites but , its showing only gray color for just one site. I tried to upload new excel sheet with different graphs but still it shows the same gray color.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve , here the solution: http://windowsadminblog.blogspot.in/2012/12/excel-web-access-graphs-showing-gray.html

Comment: Be sure to include your solution within the text of your answer in order to avoid future broken links.